# What’s this symbol in Europe that looks a bit like an upside-down V, or ⩘?

Tags: europe, money, price, french-language

I noticed on a bistrot's price board, this symbol was used to denote prices. It looks a little bit like an upside-down V, and the closest match shapecatcher.com could find was [⩘](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/10840). It could also be compared to a segment of a [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave).

An example of prices from an image of the menu at Brasserie Lola follows (since it’s not my image, I can’t share it):

> Entree 1  –  €5–
>   Entree 2  –  €7–
>   ...
>   Plat 1  –  ⩘4,5.
>   Plat 2  –  ⩘3,5.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72370/discussion-on-question-by-hart-simha-whats-this-symbol-in-europe-that-looks-a-b).

Comment: This picture just begs for more questions. What, for instance, are those letters that look like Γ, +, and ω?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I cannot understand what you're referring to. To me it seems like completely normal handwriting (and even the 1 feels different from the description the OP gave). For the record the first line is *rolles* , the second is *aux girolles* the third is *[c]éleri truffe* and the third is *[po]mmes vertes*.

Comment: @DenisNardin What's the unicode character for sarcasm?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev it's "/s"

Comment: @DenisNardin indeed, the `1`s in the photo which has been uploaded are more readily recognizable to me than what I originally saw

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It's the number one, with a left-hand stroke, and is not uncommon in European countries, including France.

This from [Wikipedia on Regional Handwriting Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_handwriting_variation), (including the illustration):

> **The numeral 1** — This numeral is sometimes written with a serif at the top extending downward and to the left. People in some parts of Europe extend this stroke nearly the whole distance to the baseline. It is sometimes written with horizontal serifs at the base; without them it can resemble the shape of the numeral 7, which has a near-vertical stroke without a crossbar, and a shorter horizontal top stroke. This numeral is often written as a plain vertical line without an ear at the top; this form is easily confused with the capital letter I and with the lower-case letter L.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72340/discussion-on-answer-by-giorgio-whats-this-currency-symbol-in-paris-that-looks).

Comment: Seven, in most countries, DOES have a cross-bar.

Comment: In casually-written German, e.g. on menu blackboards like this, I've even seen the "serif" (as this article calls it) extend *below* the baseline.

Answer (score 20):

It's just the number "one". It's not a French specificity, in continental Europe (and in most countries with (Continental) European influence) we (almost) never handwrite the number "1" as "I" like english-speaking people do. Also, we usually handwrite 7 with a middle bar so there is no mistaking possible.

Comment: Not so wrong - I've been to several countries in Europe, South America and Asia, and the first time I saw yhe number 1 handwritten like "I" was when I travelled to Australia.

Comment: It may be a European specialty but not specifically parisian or french

Comment: This answer is not *wrong*, but it is an exxageration: *we always handwrite 7 with a middle bar* is definitely too strong.

Comment: Right, changed "always" to "usually"

Comment: I still not agree with the answer. Big parts of continental Europe do write the 1 in a different way than the one in the question. And the 7 can be written several different ways, often by one person depending on the situation.

Comment: @Willeke - like where? I've literally never seen 1 written as I in my whole life traveling Europe.

Comment: @Davor Here in the Netherlands I also see the digit 'one' written as "1" in public places, but in handwriting and on a blackboard, it's clearly an "I".

Comment: Indeed the Netherlands, and as far as I remember Scandinavia, parts of Germany and other places I do not remember by location. As there are several acceptable versions, most people do not notice which ones are used, until they run into one they are not familiar with.

Comment: [Here's a page of calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEIjn.jpg) I (born and educated in Denmark) did long before seeing this questions. The ones are all simple vertical lines -- fiddly-bits on hand-written ones are certainly not universal in continental Europe.

Comment: @Coke How do you come to the conclusion this answer would not answer the question?

Answer (score 6):

Because the writing of numbers varies between anglophone and continental countries, I have written down the different variation of numbers I myself encountered in Europe (The third 6 is a write error):

[image]

As you can see, most of the problems arise with 1, 4, 6, 7 and 9.

The first column is how I personally write the numbers (German).

Both 1 and 4 can have a underscore.
As you also see, some numbers like 1, 2 and 4 have sweeps if you write with pen.
Both 6 and 9 can end vertically, with can cause the 6 look like b.
7 has *always* a horizontal bar.
The third 9 has a vertical extension above on the right side of the circle, I hope it is prominent enough.

If someone has also a notable variation, I can add it later to the paper.

Comment: As an American who has traveled a number of times to Europe and Asia, all of these look reasonably normal to me except the 4 with an underscore.  I don't think I've ever seen that in the wild before, and if I saw it without context, I would not have understood it.

Comment: @GrandOpener 4 with the underscore is for when it is easily misread as 9. When I hand-write 4's they can look like 9s... ( rightmost 4 is close to the handmotion I use, yet the result of mine is better...) which in sloppy cases look a bit like the center 9.

Comment: @StianYttervik I don't doubt that it exists--some of the handwriting I've seen in Asia has been truly bizarre (9 drawn like a lollipop with the bar coming down from the middle of the circle stands out in my memory as one of the weirder ones). I suppose the underline 4 must be somewhat rare or regional though--I've honestly never seen it despite recognizing all the others.  (FWIW I personally was taught the 4 with the open top, so I don't have that problem.)

Answer (score 4):

[This PDF](http://ekladata.com/kCFTlWbUPUs5dEo3p72WATJj6lc/ecriture-cursive.pdf) looks to me like standard French school-writing.

Here's an copy-and-paste of what it says the hand-written numbers should look like:

[image]

So you're seeing a (quite well-formed) `1` -- the photograph in the question shows the ascender on the left (correctly) starting about half-way-up.

[image]

... which I find easy to recognise as a `1` (and a good argument for requiring a cross-bar on the `7`, to disambiguate it).

I don't know what character you used to represent that in type, i.e. "⩘" ... I didnt recognise that as a 1 because the ascender starts at the bottom of the line.